# How to install custom recovery on Micromax Canvas Nitro A310?

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-android

I am unable to flash anything from recovery mode on my rooted (kinguser) android 4.4.2 (micromax canvas nitro A310). Red triangle with exclaimation mark & unable to do anything, even not able to perform "User Backup". Shows error - write error, short write.

Can somebody help to delete stock recovery & install custom. CWM recovery does not have updated custom recovery for model A310 (android 4.4.2).

Answer (score 1):

The best recovery for Canvas Nitro is Philz Recovery.
Below is the link at XDA for Philz recovery along with installation procedures, etc.

[Philz Recovery [XDA]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/a310/general/recovery-philz-touch-recovery-micromax-t2989676)

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest Team Win Recovery Project (TWRP) image to your SD card. Then download [Mobileuncle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileuncle.toolbox) from the Play Store and use it to flash the TWRP image.